# SQL Server where are my cascade cycles?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

In my database, there are two tables: `[Node]` and `[NodeDetail]`.

[Node]:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Node] 
(
    [ID]                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                 NVARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
    [Description]          NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [NodeTypeID]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_Node] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]),

    CONSTRAINT [fk_Node_NodeTypeID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([NodeTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[NodeType] ([ID]) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_NodeName] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([Name] ASC, [NodeTypeID] ASC)
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Node_NodeTypeID]
ON [dbo].[NodeType]([NodeTypeID] ASC);
```

[NodeDetail]:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NodeDetail] 
(
    [ID]                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [ParentNodeID]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ChildNodeID]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [UnimportantProperty]  INT              NULL,
    [ImportantProperty]    DECIMAL (19, 6)  DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    …

    CONSTRAINT [pk_NodeDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_NodeDetail_ChildNodeID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ChildNodeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Node] ([ID]) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fk_NodeDetail_ParentNodeID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentNodeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Node] ([ID]) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_NodeDetail_ParentNodeID]
ON [dbo].[NodeDetail]([ParentNodeID] ASC);


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_NodeDetail_ChildNodeID]
ON [dbo].[NodeDetail]([ChildNodeID] ASC);
```

When I try to deploy to a real database in Azure, it starts complaining that `fk_NodeDetail_ChildNodeID`

> may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Now, I'm trying to see where these cycles could happen and how to break them, but I can't identify.

Insofar as I understand, when `[dbo].[Node] where [ID] = 1` is deleted, all entries in `[dbo].[NodeDetail] where [ChildNodeID] = 1` will be deleted. At the same time, all entries in `[dbo].[NodeDetail] where [ParentNodeID] = 1` will also be deleted.

Any properties in `[dbo].[NodeDetail]` are never foreign keys in any other tables, so I do not understand where it can propagate.

The whole thing unfolds into a tree. Goal is to make sure that whenever a node is deleted or changes its ID (may happen), the node detail which connects it to another node will be deleted or updated accordingly. There is an ID on `NodeDetail` because between two different Nodes there can be multiple `NodeDetail`s with different properties.

EDIT:

So I found the cause, which is the two FK referencing the same column in the same table. In the mind of SQL Server, it is possible that when both point to the same entry, changing that entry will require changing both FKs. Through some inconceivable logic, this means a cycle or multiple cascade path.

The bad news: this is not fixed by a CHECK constraint (if your version supports it). To fold a tree into the database, procedures and triggers must be used to get rid of garbage.

Comment: It's not a cycle, but it's not inconceivable at all that it's a "multiple cascade path" — seems pretty clear that that's exactly what it is :)

Comment: @hobbs I reckon you’re right, but I don’t see how it’s different from cascading into two different tables. After all, you’re not barred from setting up a cascade constraint in a different table.